# Magento 2 duplicate PHPSESSID cookie when using session_start() in custom php script

Tags: magento2, ajax, session

I have custom php script that is called with ajax. It must be stand-alone script to save spent resources because it is called 1-3 times per each page load. Init Magento for each ajax call would cause server overload.

In that stand-alone script I use session so I start it with `session_start()`.

Problem:
Some customers (in rare cases) reported that it removes products from cart and starts new session when ajax call to this script is loaded. I could not reproduce the problem on my side, but I suspect this is the problem:
[image]

As you can see in the image, it will create another PHPSESSID cookie. I read that modern browsers should not care about the leading dot, but here it will duplicate cookie.

Does anybody have any hint why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I have a Magento site running on site.com and a Symfony application running on app.site.com. Magento was setting the cookie domain as ".site.com" which was conflicting with the cookie (PHPSESSID) that was needed by app.site.com.

The solution I found was to set the "session.name" value directly in the Magento virtual host (I'm using Nginx)

```
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "session.name = magento";
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by renaming session inside custom script:
`session_name('UNIQUE_NAME');`. This works because I don't need to share session between Magento and custom script.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the solution on my own question. 
[Magento 2: User cant logged in into to account page, no error showing!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225134/magento-2-user-cant-logged-in-into-to-account-page-no-error-showing/225620)

I got the solution for it, i installed the php chat plugin on the server and embed into magento 2 website. the issue was coming from the cookies that both of them was generated on the same url. when you look at the PHPSSID into the inspect element , it will show duplicate PHPSSID and one of them was conflicted with origenal one. Solution - i have created the subdomian and copy the chat code into the subdomain. that completely solve my problem.