# Magento 2: User cant logged in into to account page, no error showing!

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, login, customer-account

I have Migrated Magento 2 website from subdomain to root. after migration user cant logged into the account but admin is working fine.
if user clear the cache and try to login , login works fine but when the cookies expire it wont work.
Everything look perfect but dont know what can be the issue.

Comment: Did you check the logs of magento 2?

Comment: Kindly check magento log files when user are not able to login.

Comment: it doest not produce any error in log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for it, i installed the php chat plugin on the server and embed into magento 2 website. the issue was coming from the cookies that both of them was generated on the same url. when you look at the PHPSSID into the inspect element , it will show duplicate PHPSSID and one of them was conflicted with origenal one.
Solution - i have created the subdomian and copy the chat code into the subdomain. that completely solve my problem.

Comment: Can you explin More ? I didn't find chat plugin for php server

Answer (score 0):

It must be your cookie domain issue.

Check at **core_config_data**  database table

run the sql query

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%cookie%';
```

to check the setting.

**Cookie domain value should be domain.**

Comment: i tried both with input the url and null value. still same

Answer (score 0):

After the Magento upgrade, if your Magento project faces an error on the user login page, just go to the back-end of Magento(admin)>customers>all customers>(your user). Select the user and make changes from pending to approved
Go on..

Answer (score 0):

check var/session/ folder and if the session is not there then check app/etc/env.php for session storage.